# Why is pip executing python version 3.8.3 instead of later version?

Tags: python, pip, valueerror

On Windows 10, pip install pandas-datareader failed
The traceback showed that this problem occurred in a Python 3.8 file located in `c:\Program Files\WindowsApps`

I do not have access to the WindowsApps folder so cannot check contents of the files.

I upgraded pip, but problem remained.
I installed Python 3.9.6 for my user and restarted, but problem remained.
I uninstalled my local version of version 3.9.6, which was a mistake as it uninstalled the pymongo package.
I reinstalled Python 3.9.6 for all users i.e at C:\Program Files level. Problem remained.
The python path in my user path variable points to a Python38 version, but not the one that the failing code is executing from so seems pointless to change.

Why is 3.8.3 version of runpy.py executing instead of 3.9.6 version?

```
N:\>cd onedrive

N:\OneDrive>cd python

N:\OneDrive\python>pip install pandas-datareader
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 155, in _get_module_details
    code = loader.get_code(mod_name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 981, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 911, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

## RESOLUTION

I think the reason that an older version of Python was being executed was, as bfris suggested, because there was a python 3.8 install in a superior location on the path.
From Apps & Features on Windows 10, I uninstalled Python 3.8 (64bit), as suggested by Anthony Sottile. The uninstall deleted my local install and the Windows install also.
From System Properties, I changed my user path variable to point to Python 3.9 at my chosen installation location of : c\Program Files\ Python39\Scripts

pip install now working

Comment: this is the windows store python -- I'd recommend uninstalling the windows store python and instead using the installers from python.org

Comment: `pip` run whichever version of Python it was installed with, since that's where its shebang points.

Comment: If you want Python 3.9's pip, run `python39 -m pip`, where `python39` is, well, your Python 3.9 executable.

Comment: I think windows searches through %PATH% environment variable and stops on the first instance of pip.exe that it finds. If the system level Python is first in path, then that pip will run. From a command prompt, you can do `cd -d "C:\Users\Neil\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts"` to change to the Scripts directory you want and then do `pip install pandas-datareader` and the package will be installed to your local user pip.